# How to create an A* algorithm in lists using python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an A* algorithm in Python. The matter of fact is that I don't understand anything on all the websites I'm searching, and this is why I ask on stack overflow. Here is my list :

```
[
  ['X', '_', '_', '_', 'O', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', '_', '_', '_', 'O'], 
  ['_', '_', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '_', '_', '_', '_'], 
  ['O', 'O', '_', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', '_', '_'], 
  ['_', 'O', 'O', '_', 'O', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'O', 'O', '_', 'O'], 
  ['_', '_', 'O', '_', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', '_', 'O', 'O', 'V', 'O']
]
```

I have to find a path to join X to V, and the O are obstacles. I also have to return it like:

```
A1;B1;C1;D1;D2;E2;E3;F3;F4;G4;H4;I4;I3;J3;J2;L2;L3;L4;L5
```

I tried to use the A*(star) algorithm, without success. I also tried the recursive way, like that :

```
 def search(x, y):
    if data[x][y] == 'V':
        print('found at %d,%d' % (x, y))
        return True
    elif data[x][y] == 'O':
        print('wall at %d,%d' % (x, y))
        return False
    elif data[x][y] == '_':
        print('visited at %d,%d' % (x, y))
        return False
    print ('visiting %d,%d' % (x, y))
    data[x][y] = 3
    if ((x < len(data)-1 and search(x+1, y))
        or (y > 0 and search(x, y-1))
        or (x > 0 and search(x-1, y))
        or (y < len(data)-1 and search(x, y+1))):
        return True
    return False
    
  search(0, 0)
```

but it didn't work too. Probably because my data wasn't like a grid.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: What do you have trouble understanding. Also adding to @DMalan's comment, can you add to code you have so far?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? If you don't understand anything then you will not undestand our answers too. And Stackoverflow is not place to write full tutorial and explain all from scratch

Comment: you could at least try to use `recursion` to visit all places and check if there is path.

Comment: I edited my question with code I tried

Comment: you return only `True`/`False` so you can't see path. You should return something like  `True,[path]` and `False,[]` to get path. It would also to add elements to path. Eventually to make it faster you could also use array with visited cells - and check if you already visited cell.

Comment: your big mistake is checking `data[x][y] == '_':` - when you get `_` then you should't `return` but run rest of code. And you should check very direction separatelly. If some direction gives True then you should return `[[x,y]] + path_from_recursion`

Comment: other problem is in `y < len(data)-1` - you should use `len(data[0])` instead of `len(data)`

Comment: frankly `data[x][y]` is missleading because it should be rather `data[y][x]` (or more readble `data[row][col]`)

Answer (score 0):

This is not `A*(star)` solution but only explanation for code in question.

---

You return only `True`/`False` so you can't see path.

You should return something like `True,[path]` and `False,[]` or `False,None` to get path.

And first you shouldn't check `_` but you should run rest of code.

And in recursion you should check every direction separatelly and do

```
status, path = search(x-1, y)
if status is True:
    return True,[[x,y]]+path
```

Other problem is in `y < len(data)-1` - you should use `len(data[0])` instead of `len(data)`

Frankly, `data[x][y]` can be missleading because it nested list keeps it as `data[row][col]` which means `data[y][x]` - but I skip this problem.

Other important element - you should have list with already visited cells and skip code when you visit again the same cell.

At the end you should get list like `[ [1,0], [2,0], ...]` which you have to convert to list `[ "A1", "A2", ...]` and later join all strings using `";".join(...)`

---

Full working code for normal recursion:

It search only one path - so it doesn't have to be the best path.

```
data = [
  ['X', '_', '_', '_', 'O', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', '_', '_', '_', 'O'], 
  ['_', '_', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '_', '_', '_', '_'], 
  ['O', 'O', '_', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', '_', '_'], 
  ['_', 'O', 'O', '_', 'O', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'O', 'O', '_', 'O'], 
  ['_', '_', 'O', '_', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', '_', 'O', 'O', 'V', 'O']
]

visited = []

def search(x, y):
    if [x,y] in visited:
        return False,None
    
    visited.append([x,y])
    
    if data[x][y] == 'V':
        print('found at %d,%d' % (x, y))
        return True,[[x,y]]
    
    if data[x][y] == 'O':
        print('wall at %d,%d' % (x, y))
        return False,None
    
    #elif data[x][y] == '_':
    #    print('visited at %d,%d' % (x, y))
    #    return False,[]
    
    print('visiting %d,%d' % (x, y))
    data[x][y] = 3

    # left
    if x > 0:
        status, path = search(x-1, y)
        if status is True:
            return True,[[x,y]]+path

    # right
    if x < len(data)-1:
        status, path = search(x+1, y)
        if status is True:
            return True,[[x,y]]+path
           
    # top
    if y > 0:
        status, path = search(x, y-1)
        if status is True:
            return True,[[x,y]]+path
        
    # bottom
    if y < len(data[0])-1:
        status, path = search(x, y+1)
        if status is True:
            return True,[[x,y]]+path
    
    return False,None
    
status, path = search(0, 0)
print(path)

cells = []
for x, y in path:
    cells.append( f"{chr(65+y)}{x+1}" )
    
print( ";".join(cells) )
```

Results:

```
visiting 0,0
visiting 1,0
wall at 2,0
visiting 1,1
visiting 0,1
visiting 0,2
wall at 1,2
visiting 0,3
visiting 1,3
wall at 2,3
visiting 1,4
wall at 0,4
visiting 2,4
wall at 3,4
visiting 2,5
wall at 1,5
visiting 3,5
visiting 4,5
wall at 4,4
visiting 4,6
visiting 3,6
wall at 2,6
visiting 3,7
wall at 2,7
wall at 4,7
visiting 3,8
visiting 2,8
wall at 1,8
visiting 2,9
visiting 1,9
visiting 0,9
wall at 0,8
visiting 0,10
visiting 1,10
wall at 2,10
visiting 1,11
visiting 0,11
wall at 0,12
visiting 2,11
visiting 3,11
found at 4,11

[[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5], [4, 6], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [2, 8], [2, 9], [1, 9], [0, 9], [0, 10], [1, 10], [1, 11], [2, 11], [3, 11], [4, 11]]

A1;A2;B2;B1;C1;D1;D2;E2;E3;F3;F4;F5;G5;G4;H4;I4;I3;J3;J2;J1;K1;K2;L2;L3;L4;L5
```